# How do I modify the default location of report library exports from ax 2009 into Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I have a DEV, TEST, and a Production environment for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009. I have set up SSRS reporting as well in each environment. When exporting a report library to Visual Studio, AX saves the project to a default location. This location is the same for all environments. I would like to modify this location so that I can have a different location for each environment. I can not find where this default location is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the location where the projects are exported is found in the /Client/bin/Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.ReportsDeployment.dll

The Class Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Deployment.Reports.ExportOperations expose the path using this method:

```
private static string get_DeveloperProjectPath()
{
    return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Dynamics AX Projects");
}
```

In other words, the path is hard coded, and is relevant to the current user. It can not be differentiated by adding some X++ code or other parameters, only by logging in as a different user.

Answer (score 1):

For a AX 2009 environment, you are better off using the default paths and names, and instead separate the environments by having multiple SSRS instances, one for each environment. It will generate less issues, and will be an easier, safer and quicker solution than overriding the default paths. Just run the SSRS installation multiple times and create new named SSRS instances, if you need them all on the same box.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is not with SSRS, but with the location on my local machine that AX chooses to copy the report library files. Each instance of AX chooses the same location to dump files to. The files are named the same and will overwrite. Currently AX dumps the files to users/current user/documents/Dynamics AX Projects

Comment: You don't need to worry so much about where the files are located locally, just let it overwrite and continue your development and adjustments in Visual Studio. Remember that Visual Studio is just your temporary working space for editing these report. When you are done and the changes are saved back to the AOT, you will deploy it from there and you may just as well scrap whatever files put down on the file system in order for Visual Studio to load the Report Library.

Comment: The problem is that AX will not show any record of what was changed. For audit purposes, we need to have record of the changes, so overwrites are not acceptable. I need to have a separate location for each environment. There is a default location and it must be stored somewhere.

Comment: The problem is that the paths are hardcoded into the managed dll:

private static string get_DeveloperProjectPath()
{
    return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Dynamics AX Projects");
}

So if you really need to separate the export paths, you will have to login as different users on that machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info...and that really sucks! I will have to find a work around now.

Comment: What you can do is use the built-in MorphX Version Control to create yourself revisions of the Report Libraries. That way you can revert and get hold of previous versions of that AOT-node. Check it out.